# Conversion of time string from AMPM to Military in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I apologize in advance for what probably seems like a duplicate question, but I have attempted every solution I could find, and nothing seems to be working.

I have a table with time stored separately as a varchar.  The value of a particular record is "6:00 PM"

I have tried every function and conversion in MySQL, but cannot get this thing to convert to military time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider storing times, not as a `VARCHAR`, but as a [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).  That way you can format it as you wish with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

What you can do here is use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to *convert* the string to a `DATETIME`, then use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format it.

```
-- Let's say `time` is the value "6:00 PM"
-- This should return "18:00"
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%l:%i %p'), '%k:%i') AS milTime;
```